# How to populate a dictionary from another with same keys but values cumulated

Tags: c#, linq

I am looking for a help in solving an exercise using C#, LINQ.

I have a dictionary with `DateTime` as key and a `decimal` as value. I am trying to write a method that returns another dictionary with a value that is sum of all values of previous months and current month within that year. For the next year, the process repeats.

Input dictionary:

```
01/31/2015  100
02/28/2015  100
03/31/2015  100
;
; and so on
;
01/31/2017  200
02/28/2017  200
03/31/2017  200
```

Output should be as below:

```
01/31/2015  100
02/28/2015  200
03/31/2015  300
;
;
01/31/2017  200
02/28/2017  400
03/31/2017  600
```

Here is what I did so far. It computes the total but not resetting for the next year. In Jan 2016, it adds the value of Jan to the previous sum. I guess a GroupBy is needed before I write aggregate().

```
public static IDictionary<DateTime, decimal?> RunningTotal_NotResettingForNextYear(this IDictionary<DateTime, decimal?> inputDictionary)
{

    IDictionary<DateTime, decimal?> runningTotalDictinary =
        new Dictionary<DateTime, decimal?>(inputDictionary.Count);
    inputDictionary.Aggregate((decimal?)0, (sum, value) =>
    {
        sum = sum + value.Value;
        runningTotalDictinary.Add(value.Key, sum);
        return sum;
    });

    return runningTotalDictinary;
}
```

Comment: looking at your output, it seems that the total resets on each new year which seems to contradict the method name `RunningTotal_NotResettingForNextYear`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The missing part is `GroupBy` method.

- First, group inputDictionary by year.
- Then compute the new value for each item with an accumulator (F# inspired) group by group
- Merge groups into one liste.
- Create the new dictionary.

Then the final code :

```
var newDico = inputDictionary.OrderBy(i => i.Key).GroupBy(i => i.Key.Year).SelectMany(
    group =>
        {
            decimal? accumulator = 0;
            return
            group.Select(
                element =>
                    new { Key = element.Key, Value = (accumulator += element.Value)});
        }).ToDictionary(accGroupItem => accGroupItem.Key, accGroupItem => accGroupItem.Value);
```

Or with a temp accumulator dictionary :

```
var dicoAcc = inputDictionary
                  .Select(i => i.Key.Year)
                  .Distinct()
                  .ToDictionary(year => year, _ => (decimal?)0);

var newDico = inputDictionary
                  .ToDictionary(i => i.Key, i => dicoAcc[i.Key.Year] += i.Value);
```

Comment: Hi Kalten,Thank you so much. I tried the second suggestion " temp accumulator dictionary" which worked perfect. will try the first option too.

Answer (score 1):

```
int year = 0;
decimal yearlyTotal = 0;
foreach (var kvp in sourceDict.OrderBy(x => x.Key))
{
  if (kvp.Key.Year != year)
  {
    year = kvp.Year;
    yearlyTotal = 0;
  }
  yearlyTotal += kvp.Value;
  destDict[kvp.Key] = yearlyTotal;
}
```

Comment: Hi wablab,thank you for taking time answering my question. This solution also worked. Could not recommend two answers :-(